# Put unit tests in unpackaged metadata?

Tags: unit-test, 2gp

We were having discussions about putting unit test data in static resources. The concern was that the test data is not needed by the application itself, only the unit tests, so do we want to have this data using up our static resources quota?

The suggestion was to put the data in static resources in our 2GP unpackagedMetadata folder. That raised the question: why not put all unit tests in unpackaged metadata?

Does anyone have any comments pro/con to this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent pro towards putting your unit tests in `unpackagedMetadata`. Classes marked `@isTest` do not count their bodies towards the character limits of Apex, and it's unlikely you'll have so many of these that it would impact the 15,000 component limit of a package. The downside to having your unit tests in `unpackagedMetadata` is that subscriber orgs won't be able to run your tests to verify that your code works with their customizations.

Similarly, there is very little benefit to putting your unit test static resources into `unpackagedMetadata`. Again, if the metadata is missing, subscribers can't run your tests to verify your package is working in their org. In addition, given the maximum storage limit of 250MB of static resources, it is highly unlikely that you'll use even a significant fraction of that storage for unit test data. I would guess that even very large packages with lots of fields and objects would still only need a few hundred KB of static resource storage to replicate all the data they need.

In summary, I can't think of any significant pro to excluding this kind of metadata. The `unpackagedMetadata` feature is meant to expose data that is difficult to create in Apex, either because DML isn't allowed (e.g. Custom Metadata Types), it would cause significant problems with mixed DML errors, the component can't actually be packaged, the dependencies are expected to be fulfilled by the subscriber org, etc. I would say that you should treat `unpackagedMetadata` as a last option, not the preferred method.

Comment: Hmm. I thought the static resources limit was much smaller, in the 5MB range. Was that changed in the last few years or am I just mis-remembering?

What about custom objects needed only by unit tests? Would it make sense to put those in `unpackagedMetadata` to keep from cluttering up the package? In that case, it seems like you would want to put the associated unit tests there as well.

Comment: @silverglass 5MB per file, 250MB per org for Static Resources. It is a shared limit, so be conscientious, but no need to be excessively frugal. I would question the need for an sObject that exists only for unit tests. I feel like there'd have to be a better design choice. What would such objects and their associated unit tests provide by not being part of the package?

Comment: It's an unusual use case, but in short, our customers define custom objects with various relationship types and combinations and then provide us with a description. We then must populate and query the records in these objects. We're testing to ensure we can handle different scenarios, so we create representative objects for the tests, but we would prefer not to include them in our package.

Comment: @silverglass Dependency injection, stub API, using settings for a known standard object and field, or maybe some combination could all be viable options. Then again, maybe not... Just reiterating that this should be a last-resort option, not the path-of-least-effort option.